# Strapi keeps using local provider instead of @strapi-community/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage or @strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary

Tags: google-cloud-platform, plugins, google-cloud-storage, strapi

I read a million articles, watched many videos, and am pretty sure that my setup is exactly like the one I saw. Somehow Strapi still uses the local provider to save my media. Instead, I would like to use google cloud storage because I am using Google Cloud services for the project.

I followed this documentation with no luck https://github.com/strapi-community/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage

My Plugin config should work

```
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "@strapi-community/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage",
      providerOptions: {
        bucketName: env("STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"),
        publicFiles: true,
        uniform: false,
        serviceAccount: env.json("GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"), // replace `{}` with your serviceAccount JSON object
        baseUrl: "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + env("STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME"),
        basePath: "",
      },
    },
  },
  //...
});
```

I also tried to use the cloudinary provider: https://market.strapi.io/providers/@strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary
Which also did not work for me.

I don´t really know why so I hope someone can help me here.

thank you in advance

I just followed this tutorial step by step with a new project and it also didnt work. https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-build-a-photo-gallery-with-strapi-nextjs-and-cloudinary-1
I am really confused on what to do now

### UPDATE

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "freebreath-cms",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi-community/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage": "^4.6.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.6.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.6.1",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary": "4.7.1",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.7.1",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.0.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "strapi-provider-firebase-storage": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "b8e7aa88-f9a9-46a2-a07c-7cd29a2a2a0c"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

config/middleware.ts

```
export default [
  "strapi::errors",
  {
    name: "strapi::security",
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
          "img-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            "res.cloudinary.com",
          ],
          "media-src": [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "blob:",
            "dl.airtable.com",
            "res.cloudinary.com",
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  "strapi::cors",
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];
```

.env

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=***
API_TOKEN_SALT=***
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=***
JWT_SECRET=***

#BUCKET
GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT='{"type": "service_account","project_id": "***","private_key_id": "***","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----***\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email": "***","client_id": "***","auth_uri": "***","token_uri": "***","auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "***","client_x509_cert_url": "***"}'
STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME="***"

#CLOUDINARY
CLOUDINARY_NAME=***
CLOUDINARY_KEY="***"
CLOUDINARY_SECRET="***"
```

Comment: Hi you prolly want to post whole file, since there are ppl who use .js on typescript projects, asking why it's not working. Also is your .env defined correctly? And last but not least did you build your project after config change? You have to rebuild every time you change config...

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. My .env is correct.  I can even log the values into console on init. I also tried building it. Still not working. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Well, there is some missconf somewhere, can you add a package.json maybe, everything @strapi/ should be same version… It’s really hard to tell without actual code…

Comment: I just added some more information that might give you a deeper look into my structure

Comment: All packages that start with @strapi should be same version

Comment: unfortunately still no success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252378/discussion-between-jesko-usinger-and-antokhio).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this same issue while integrating Azure Blob storage with the Media Library.

The problem is the configuration which is added in the ./config/plugins.js file

```
//  ./config/plugins.js
module.exports = ({ env }) =>  ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage",
      providerOptions: {
        account: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT"),
        accountKey: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"),
        containerName: env("STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"),
        defaultPath: "assets",
      },
    },
  },

});
```

Strapi Version: **"4.13.6"**

Strapi will always use the most specific one and has default configurations, so if you do not specify a production environment directory Strapi Cloud will override your configuration when creating it.

The production configuration should be added to the **config/env/production/plugins.js** file.

```
//  ./config/env/production/plugins.js
module.exports = ({ env }) =>  ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: "strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage",
      providerOptions: {
        account: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT"),
        accountKey: env("STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"),
        containerName: env("STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"),
        defaultPath: "assets",
      },
    },
  },

});
```

Even if you make the changes and deploy. It took some time to reflect in the Strapi Cloud(don't know the reason)